# Pass variable from PHP to HTML and from HTML to another PHP file

Tags: php, html, variables, session, post

So I have a little problem. From `GetFbId.php` I get `Id` variable to `CheckFbId.php` in following `session_start(); $id = $_SESSION['id'];` . After check is success (no user in database) It redirecting to `RegForm.html` in following: `header('Location: RegForm.html');` I need somehow to pass `Id` variable to `RegForm.html` and from here (after registration completed) It should pass all data + Id variable to `RegInsert.php`.

In conclusion `RegInsert.php` inserting data to database successfully, except *FB User Id* which should be taken from:
`GetFbId.php` > `CheckFbId.php` > `RegForm.html` > `RegInsert.php`.

My problem is that I can't successfully pass that variable from php to html and from html to php. Any help?

`CheckFbId.php` looks like:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","xxx","xxxx","xxxx");

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FB_Id = '".$id."'");

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) 
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}     
if ($query->num_rows) {
    echo "Already  registered";
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['fb_id'] = $id; 
    header("Location: registration.html?id='$id'");
}    
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

`RegForm.html` looks like:

```
      <form class="form"  method="post" action="register.php">
        <h2>Registracijos forma</h2><hr/>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">

        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">

        <label>City: </label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city">

        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
      </form>
```

`RegInsert.php` looks like:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$fb_id = $_POST['id'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");


    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (FB_Id, First_Name, Last_Name, City, Email) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?) ")) 
    {
        if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) 
        {
            printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        } 
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $fb_id, $first_name, $last_name, $city, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->error != '') 
        {
           echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
        } else 
        {
           echo 'success';
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else 
    {
       echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
    }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Keep it in the session, for example `$_SESSION['checked_id']`. Or change your html form page to a php file.

Comment: I don't know really how to use It in HTML and send It to another PHP.

Comment: So don't, keep it in the session.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the `.html` file. You want to show/pass the session array to the `.html` file? If so; you can't. Well, you can, but that would mean to instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Or, use Ajax.

Comment: Note that if you pass it to your html / php form file, you'd have to check it again in `RegInsert.php` anyway as you cannot trust user input; the user can change it in the form page.

Comment: I don't need to use sessions, just don't know other method. I need to achive this: When used open app, It should check If his FB User ID already exsists in database, If not It should open registration from and all data + user's FB Id. from registration form should be inserted to database.

Comment: So how can I get user's Facebook Id again after form is completed? To insert FB Id with form's data (Name, email, etc) to database

Comment: You don't have enough code in your question for anyone to help further. It's guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the id variable like below

```
header("Location: RegForm.html?id='$id'");
```

and can get this variable in RegForm.html page in a hidden input inside form and can pass in any page(can you change the RegForm.html to RegForm.php )

Comment: Not very safe, you'd have to rely on client-side techniques like javascript to parse it as you cannot use php in the html file.

Comment: i was just asking if he can change than change.

Comment: In your case in `CheckFbId.php` I've used: `header("Location: RegForm.html?id='$id'");` in  html form I've used: `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">` and in `RegInsert.php` I've used `$fb_id = $_POST['id'];` and It inserting FB User Id = `0`

Comment: Also I've tried in `RegInsert.php` to use `$fb_id = $_SESSION['id'];`, but in this case FB User Id = `NULL`

Comment: Are you setting the $_SESSION['id'] in GetFbId.php? If your not, of course the id variable will be null. I ask because you didn't post your code for that page.